# Change image in Javafx

Tags: java, image, user-interface, javafx, imageview

I have a window in javafx that there is  a image as defult,
now I have added an `fileChooser` to set a new file path in set a new image in the image view.
the eclips throws a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Here is the my code:

```
private void right(BorderPane layout) throws FileNotFoundException {
    image = new Image(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\itayz\\eclipse-workspace\\Lab2\\carexample.jpg"));
    imageView = new ImageView(image);
    imageView.setX(70);
    imageView.setY(55);
    imageView.setFitHeight(355);
    imageView.setFitWidth(300);

    Stage fileStage = new Stage();
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    Button button = new Button("select file");
    Scene scene = new Scene(button, 960, 600);

    fileStage.setScene(scene);
    layout.setRight(combine(button, imageView));
    button.setOnAction(e -> {
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(carStage);
        try {
            image = new Image(new FileInputStream(selectedFile.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()));
            imageView.setImage(image);
            System.out.println(selectedFile.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm().toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

this is the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\itayz\OneDrive\תמונות\20181216_204014.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at CarPane2.lambda$0(CarPane2.java:60)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try with a different jpg name. Could be a problem with encoding

Comment: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" - this is what it tells you that is wrong, so...It seems the name of your image is decoded into some symbols. Try to rename this image and avoid unusual characters.

Comment: i've change the file name and the path too:   the same errror: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\itayz\idpic.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`

Comment: If you've got a `File` and want a ***File***InputStream, why use the url? `new FileInputStream(selectedFile)` would be much simpler. If you pass a string to the constructor, it needs to be a file path, not a url. If you're using a url, you should pass it to the `Image` constructor directly which does expect an url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:
`selectedFile.getPath()`